# Save file in a folder on another server location with the purely written code on website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using mvc I am trying to save a file on another folder i.e on another server.
But earlier i was using an approach of creating two different solution and was saving the file using web request. 
i was sending the request from one solution and was geeting it on another solution.
here is my code

```
         byte[] bytes;
         var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ImagePath"];
          /*Creating the WebRequest object using the URL of SaveFile.aspx.*/
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest =
            (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create
            ("http://localhost:13492/Home/SaveImage");
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            /*Assigning the content type from the FileUpload control.*/
            webRequest.ContentType = pic.ContentType ;
            /*Creating the Header object.*/
            System.Net.WebHeaderCollection headers = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection();
            headers.Add("FileName", pic.FileName);
            /*Adding the header to the WebRequest object.*/
            webRequest.Headers = headers;
            /* Convert File Into byte array */
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pic.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            /*Getting the request stream by making use of the GetRequestStream method of WebRequest object.*/
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())//Filling request stream with image stream. 
            {
                /*Writing the FileUpload content to the request stream.*/
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, pic.ContentLength);
            }
            /*Creating a WebResponse object by calling the GetResponse method of WebRequest object.*/
            using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse webResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                /*Retrieving the response stream from the WebResponse object by calling the GetResponseStream method.*/
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string path = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

then in another solution i was getting it to save the file.

```
  public void SaveImage()
    {
        try
        {
            /*Retrieving the file name from the headers in the request. */
            string destinationFileName = Path.Combine(@"~/" + "Portfolio" + "/", Request.Headers["FileName"].ToString());
            string fileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(destinationFileName);
            //string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), Request.Headers["FileName"].ToString());
            using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
            {
                /*Getting stream from the Request object.*/
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = Request.InputStream)
                {
                    int byteStreamLength = (int)stream.Length;
                    byte[] byteStream = new byte[byteStreamLength];
                    /*Reading the stream to a byte array.*/
                    stream.Read(byteStream, 0, byteStreamLength);
                    /*Writing the byte array to the harddisk.*/
                    fileStream.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStreamLength);
                }
            }
            Response.Clear();
            /*Writing the status to the response.*/
            Response.Write(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /*Writing the error message to the response stream.*/
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

So what should i change in code so that i could save the file on another location on another server without writing the code on two different place.

Comment: if the remote server exposes the destination folder as a shared folder, and the two servers are on the same network, then you could save the file directly to the share (assuming your application has permission to do so). If the folder is not shared, then it's private to the other server and you'll have to send the server the file via another method and request that it processes it e.g. a HTTP request something like your first example, or you could use FTP or SFTP, if either of those is available to you. There are lots of different (well-understood) ways to transfer files. Do some research.

Comment: Is the second server managed by you or you are utilizing it just to save some files? We have many different approaches to save the file on the different server.

Comment: @Sandip No it is not manage by us . I am just utilizing it . can you please suggest me an approach to save the file on another server without writing the code on multiple places?

Comment: @shamisheikh What's wrong with the suggestions I already made, above (not to mention maybe making an effort and doing some of your own research into this hugely well-understood and well-documented topic online)? Of course if it's not your server, then you are stuck with the interfaces provided by those who manage the server, unless you have the ability to request that they change the config. Or do you have the option to store these files on another server entirely, and ignore the server you currently use? It's not clear.

Comment: I would suggest you go for Azure Blob Storage. Here you can store your file and then have another team to access the file from storage itself. which would be a link and can be accessed without any credentials. if this approach fits your requirement then I am happy to explain in more

Comment: @ Sandip No i cant go for azure .

Comment: @ADyson nothing wrong with the suggestions. I am really highly obliged to you for your valuable time. actually my requirement is i have to save some images on another link i.e a folder placed on different location and was able to do so but by writing some code as i've explained above. But somehow i cant write code on that link where the folder is placed. So i have to save that file from website.
and i am doing research on it . actually i m not well comfortable to play with file.

Comment: use webRequest class then.

Comment: @Sandip can you please suggest me any link .?

Comment: " somehow i cant"...what do you mean by this? You mean you don't have access to the server to deploy code on it? If you want to transfer files to another server, then _something_ has to be done to configure the remote server. You have to enable some service and/or deploy some code to receive the incoming data. It's not done by magic. So you need to find out what the server has got available (or what you can request to be made available), either file share, or FTP server, or whatever. I've already explained all this. Now you need to go and find out your next step.

Comment: @ADyson i mean i don't have access to the server to deploy code on it and it is FTP server.
Thanks you so much :)

Comment: ok so at last you mention something useful - the server has an FTP service running. Good. You can easily google code to make a file transfer by FTP using C#. Lots and lots of examples and tutorials will be available. Didn't you do that yet?

Comment: for uploading files from client side to ftp, check this sample http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/09/uploading-files-from-client-side-to-ftp.html

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution for this problem and its working fine.

```
 public static void UploadFtpFile(string folderName, string fileName)
    {

        FtpWebRequest request;
        try
        {
            //string folderName;
            //string fileName;
            string absoluteFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}/{1}/{2}", "ftp.site4now.net", folderName, absoluteFileName))) as FtpWebRequest;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
            request.ConnectionGroupName = "group";

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Close();
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestStream.Flush();
                requestStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow Below Sample**

*This sample is for creating a folder on another server over FTP protocol. Please extend it as per need.*

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://host.com/directory");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

***As per the comment by @ADyson you must enable the FTP Protocol before working using this sample***

Comment: this assumes the remote server has FTP enabled, which we don't know for sure, and also it's not clear how this snippet does anything about transferring files. It makes a folder (which may or may not be necessary) but does not transfer a file, which is the thing OP was asking about. Plus, code without an explanation is not very useful to anyone!

Comment: @ADyson. Thank you for the comment. I have updated it with a note. Also since this answer is based on the comments added to question. But, yes I have modified it to improve.

Comment: Yes FTP is enabled.

Comment: @Sandip FTP enabled was confirmed after you posted the answer!

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: thanks all of you for a valuable time and effort :) I've got a solution and its working fine.